# ImageKit async error - can't decode message body

Tags: python, django, django-imagekit

I'm using Django 1.6 and Django-ImageKit 3.2.1.

I'm trying to generate images asynchronously with ImageKit. Async image generation works locally but not on the production server.

I'm using Celery and I've tried both:

`IMAGEKIT_DEFAULT_CACHEFILE_BACKEND = 'imagekit.cachefiles.backends.Async'`

`IMAGEKIT_DEFAULT_CACHEFILE_BACKEND = 'imagekit.cachefiles.backends.Celery'`

Using the `Simple` backend (synchronous) instead of `Async` or `Celery` works fine on the production server. So I don't understand why the asynchronous backend gives me the following ImportError (pulled from the Celery log):

```
[2014-04-05 21:51:26,325: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Can't decode message body: DecodeError(ImportError('No module named s3utils',),) [type:u'application/x-python-serialize' encoding:u'binary' headers:{}]

body: '\x80\x02}q\x01(U\x07expiresq\x02NU\x03utcq\x03\x88U\x04argsq\x04cimagekit.cachefiles.backends\nCelery\nq\x05)\x81q\x06}bcimagekit.cachefiles\nImageCacheFile\nq\x07)\x81q\x08}q\t(U\x11cachefile_backendq\nh\x06U\x12ca$
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 585, in _receive_callback
    decoded = None if on_m else message.decode()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/message.py", line 142, in decode
    self.content_encoding, accept=self.accept)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 184, in loads
    return decode(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/contextlib.py", line 34, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 59, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 55, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 184, in loads
    return decode(data)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 64, in pickle_loads
    return load(BytesIO(s))
DecodeError: No module named s3utils
```

s3utils is what defines my AWS S3 bucket paths. I'll post it if need be, but the strange thing I think is that the synchronous backend has no problem importing s3utils while the asynchronous does... and asynchronous does ONLY on the production server, not locally.

I'd be SO greatful for any help debugging this. I've been wrestling this for days. I'm still learning Django and python so I'm hoping this is a stupid mistake on my part. My Google-fu has failed me.

Comment: Have you restarted your Celery worker recently?

Comment: Thanks for the nice words (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I hinted at in my comment above, this kind of thing is usually caused by forgetting to restart the worker.

It's a common gotcha with Celery. The workers are a separate process from your web server so they have their own versions of your code loaded. And just like with your web server, if you make a change to your code, you need to reload so it sees the change. The web server talks to your worker not by directly running code, but by passing serialized messages via [the broker](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html), which will say something like "call the function `do_something()`". Then the worker will read that message and—and here's the tricky part—call *its version* of `do_something()`. So even if you restart your webserver (so that it has a new version of your code), if you forget to reload the worker (which is what actually calls the function), the old version of the function will be called. In other words, you need to restart the worker any time you make a change to your tasks.

You might want to check out [the autoreload option](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#autoreloading) for development. It could save you some headaches.